# timeout command not taking effect

Tags: php

So, I've been trying to execute a script using the timeout command in php on ubuntu

the code:

```
$output = shell_exec("cd ../; timeout $time perl test.pl 127.0.0.1 80");
```

But I've noticed by the CPU percentage that it doesn't stop when it is supposed to.

I've been trying to find a fix for this for a few days but wasnt able to find one, I'm using php7.2 if that helps

Comment: Not really a lot to go on, what is the value of `$time`? If the timeout command is not given a proper interval then it will effectively do nothing.  Does this command function correctly if you echo the string, and copy paste it into a the command line?

Comment: @RyanH The command works perfectly fine when ran in a command line, I have no tried echoing the string but the $time is just a variable that gets the time from the url like this:
https://example.com/test.php?time=20

Comment: @RyanH I should maybe add that this worked perfectly fine but I had to restart my server because of a OS issue, I had made no changes to the file before and after this reset and it suddenly stopped working.

Comment: I would recommend echoing out the generated string and verifying that the content of it are what you expect the shell command to execute. ... verify that the command is starting from the correct place .... seeing shell_exec is terrifying, but seeing 'cd' in a command is even more so ... check that the user who is running apache/nginx instance has permissions to both the file and to the perl executable. ... a lot of things can happen to a filesystem/configs/users through a restart.

Comment: @RyanH I've tried echoing it and this is what I got: cd ../; timeout 5 perl test.pl 127.0.0.1 80, And these are the correct args i entered